# How can I set $_POST to equal $_POST

Tags: php, html, post

I have a lot of `$_POST` variables ... is it possible to do something like this?

I want something like this... (I know this doesn't work, because it comes out to `$_POST['POST']` ) :

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="POST" value="<?=$_POST?>"/>
</form>
```

Instead of this:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$_POST['id']?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?=$_POST['name']?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="ordernum" value="<?=$_POST['ordernum']?>"/>

    <?php 
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $_POST['ordernum']; $i++){
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="line'.$i.'" value="'.$_POST['line'.$i].'" />';
    }
    ?>
</form>
```

The reason for this is I have two forms:

- 1st Form is for inputing variables
- 2nd Form is to ask the user to verify all the variables
- Once that is submitted, I want to input this in a DB

The problem is I want to carry over the $_POST variables from the 1st Form to the DB, without having to add them with `<input type="hidden" >` in the 2nd Form

Comment: What are you asking? Are you asking to do a `foreach($_POST ... )`?

Comment: I want to carry over all the post variables... from my current form...

Comment: sessions, or serliase the array `$_SESSION['FORM']=$_POST;` OR  `serialize($_POST)`

Comment: `$_POST` is array. Input value is string. You can serialize/unserialize array. But still I don't understand what you need this for.

Comment: @u_mulder I added a reason why I want to do it to the button of my question... Is there a better solution?

Comment: If you serialize the array to a string then you can put that string into a hidden form field and de-serialize it the next time the form posts it to the server.  ASP.NET WebForms does exactly this to maintain what it calls ViewState (it just base-64 encodes the serialized string).

Comment: **BE AWARE THAT BY KEEPING IT LIKE THIS YOU HAVE A XSS LEAK** Read more about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). Put `htmlspecialchars` around the echoed data to keep your website safe.

Comment: @thew Do I have to do this around every `echo $_POST` variable? Are you saying someone able to edit my `$_POST` variable and add something like this `<?=$dbpassword?>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have 2 basic options. In personal order of preference

sessions

you can assing the whole or just part of the post array to a session

```
$_SESSION['FORM']=$_POST;
```

session_start() required before you use or set the values from the session array.

or 'hide' the values in the form by serlising the array

```
  <input type="hidden" name="POST" value="<? echo serialize($_POST); ?>"/>
```

at the other end you use `unserialize();` to get the array back